# mvc Html.BeginForm add View in form action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a view with a `Html.BeginForm` helper like this :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
```

When the page was downloaded, in the source code I see that the action value is right and is equal to /MyApplicationName/Account/Login, but when I click on the submit button, the next error message is showed:

> Requested URL: /MyApplicationName/View/Account/Login .

Why the url has the View before the controller/action?
Thank you from your help.

Comment: Is any js code hijacking the form submit and updating the form action attribute value ?

Comment: Check your default route in RouteConfig.cs

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: Show the code in the `Login()` POST method.

Comment: There was a js that has set the 'window.location.href' in wrong mode as suggested by @Shiju. Problem solved. Thank you all.